# Continuity of $\sqrt[3]{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, proof-writing, upper-lower-bounds

Prove that $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is continuous.  *There are many solutions for this available; this question is to verify and critique* my *proof, which uses an approach different and, IMO, simpler, than the solutions I've seen.*

**Proof:** By definition, $\sqrt[3]x$ is continuous if $\lim_{h \to 0} \sqrt[3]{x+h} = \sqrt[3]x$.  At $x = 0,\lim \sqrt[3]{x+h} = \sqrt[3]x$ by the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limit, with $\delta < \epsilon^3.$  To show this for $x \neq 0$, we first show that $\lim_{b \to 0} \sqrt[3]{1+b} = 1.$

Assume $b > 0$.  Then $1 < \sqrt[3]{1 + b} < 1 +b$, since $1^3 < 1 + b < (1 + b)^3$.  Similarly, if $-1 < b < 0$, then $1 > \sqrt[3]{1 + b} > 1 +b.$  By the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{b \to 0} \sqrt[3]{1+b} = 1.$

Write $b = \frac h x$, and $\sqrt[3]{x+h} = \sqrt[3] x \sqrt[3] {1 + b} \to \sqrt[3] x.$  QED.

**Questions:** Is this proof correct, rigorous, and well written? How can it be improved?

---

**Update:** Drawing on Thomas Andrews' very helpful critique, I revise the proof that $\lim_{b \to 0} \sqrt[3]{1+b} = 1$ as follows:

Restrict $|b| < 1$.  Assume $b > 0$.  Then $b^2 < b$, so $(1 - b)^3 =  (1-b)(1 + b^2 - 2b) < 1 - b < 1 + b < (1 +b)^3.$  Likewise, if $b < 0$, we have by symmetry $(1-b)^3 > 1 + b > (1 + b)^3$. By the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{b \to 0} \sqrt[3]{1+b} = 1.$

**Or better yet:**

Observe that for all $a > 0, a^3 < a$ if and only if $a < 1$.  Restrict $|b| < 1$.  Assume $b > 0$.  Then $(1 -b)^3 < 1 - b < 1 + b < (1 + b)^3.$  And, if $b < 0$, by symmetry we have a similar inequality: $(1 +b)^3 < 1 + b < 1 - b < (1 - b)^3.$ By the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{b \to 0} \sqrt[3]{1+b} = 1.$

*Does this solve the deficiencies of the original proof?*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140880/discussion-on-question-by-srobertjames-continuity-of-sqrt3x).